# how to satisfy rpm user and group dependencies that already exist?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I was installing an rpm and satisfied the other needed rpm dependencies but still had a dependencie requiring a user and group entry (name=lp).  I already have user and group named 'lp', so why doesn't rpm recognize them?  More importantly how can I get rpm to recognize that the user+group dependencies are already satisfied?

If I am creating a spec file for an rpm, how can I specify in a spec file, that installation of said spec file satisfies some user and/or group dependency?

This doesn't seem to be something I would put in a %pre (that used to be how I might do it), but seems to be a dependency that is inserted (or detected) in the rpm database.  I don't want to try to create a user/group on the system, only detect (or satisfy the need for such) in the rpm DB.

Here is the output of rpm, showing the "reqs" of the package.

```
rpm -q --requires  cups-config-2.3.3-3.1.x86_64.rpm
config(cups-config) = 2.3.3-3.1
group(lp) 
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1 rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <=> 5.4.18-1 
user(lp)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an RPM that can also manipulate files and add users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197374/create-an-rpm-that-can-also-manipulate-files-and-add-users)

Answer (score 0):

See [Dynamic allocation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/UsersAndGroups/#_dynamic_allocation) section of Fedora Packaging Guidelines. You may even read a whole chapter.

Comment: I don't want dynamic allocation for the user or groups.  The user/group(s) already exist on the physical system, but not in the rpm DB.  It's not clear that the section you point to allows for static specification of user/groups to be added to the DB for user/groups that already exist.

Comment: Also, dynamic allocation has nothing to do with why RPM isn't able to detect   user/groups that already exist.  What I need is how to do _Static_Allocation_ to define a user/group in the RPM database that already exists on the system where the package is being installed. This is purely to satisfy user/group prereqs that some packages specify.

Comment: The ,macro `%sysusers_create_compat` (that is referred in that linked doc) does that. It actually calls /usr/lib/rpm/sysusers.generate-pre.sh which calls `getent passwd $USER` and add the user only if the user does not already exists.

Comment: And for static allocation, the workflow is the same. It is described in that referred documentation in section 'Soft static allocation'

Comment: That's for using scriptlets to manage user/group.  When testing for requisites, scriptlets aren't run.  The requirement for a specific user/group seems to be a static requirement in the rpm as it is detectable as a 'requisite'.

Answer (score -1):

<s>RPMs don't natively handle users/groups, you need to have them in your scriptlets. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197374/create-an-rpm-that-can-also-manipulate-files-and-add-users/11199816#11199816).</s>

Well... **T**oday **I** **L**earned...

So it seems RPM version 4.19 [*will support* users and groups](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/users_and_groups.html). The problem is, that as of today, the latest version available on `rpm.org` says "RPM 4.19.0 BETA released (Aug 02 2023)". So I don't know where you got the RPM, but it was built with BETA software.

That version of `rpm` is not going to be supported (yet) by any traditional distributions (*e.g.* Fedora).

Comment: scriptlets are where you can add them, but scriplets are not run when you try to do a test install.  The user/groups come up as prerequisites before any scripts are run.

Comment: please example in updated question, above.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You are in uncharted territory; good luck.